# Ordenar Select por ID javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Pessoal eu tenho um select via ajax que puxo os dados do meu banco
só que na hora de apresentar o select, não estou conseguindo apresentar por ordem de **ID** **Crescente**,

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <div id="lista-hospitais-loader" class="loader-120 center-block"></div>
                <div id="lista-hospitais-content" class="form-group">
                    <label>Selecione o Centro:</label><br />
                    <select id="hospital-change-list" data-live-search="true" data-width="75%"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Gerencial/Centro/GetHospitais',
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var option = '<option value="' + data[i].CentroId + '">' + data[i].CentroId + ' - ' + data[i].Nome + '</option>';
                    $('#hospital-change-list').append(option);
                }

                $('#lista-hospitais-loader').fadeOut(1300, function () {
                    $('#hospital-change-list').selectpicker();
                    $('#lista-hospitais-content').fadeIn(100);
                    $('#change-ok').removeAttr('disabled');
                });
            }
        });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu pode ordenar o teu drop utilizando o método `sort();`, ele possibilita a ordenação dos elementos através de qualquer atributo, para mais informações sobre o método da uma olhada na [documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp),

*No seu caso ficaria:

```
var drop = $('#hospital-change-list option');

drop.sort(function(a,b){
    a = a.value;
    b = b.value;

    return a-b;
});

$('#hospital-change-list').html(drop);
```

segue um exemplo funcional de como o método funciona:

```js
var drop = $('#drop option');

drop.sort(function(a,b){
    a = a.id;
    b = b.id;
 
    return a-b;
});

$('select').html(drop);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop">
  <option id="1">Um</option>
  <option id="3">Tres</option>
  <option id="4">Quatro</option>
  <option id="2">Dois</option>
  <option id="7">Sete</option>
  <option id="5">Cinco</option>
  <option id="6">Seis</option>
</select>
```

Comment: amigo eu consegui resolver aqui, mais agradeço mesmo assim a sua ajuda!

Comment: Maravilha, mas fica o registro de como "Ordenar Select por ID javascript" :D

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal consegui resolver, quando eu faço o select no banco, o meu order by estava puxando pelo nome, nisso eu alterei pelo ID do centro!